# What does it mean if the ROC scores are quite different when using the Stratified K fold with and without shuffling?

Tags: cross-validation, roc, scikit-learn, stratification

I'm currently building a random forest classification and trying to measure the model performance by the [mean ROC area].

With the same data set:

- When I use cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None), the [mean ROC area] = 0.72
- When I use cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=1), the [mean ROC area] is much worse: = 0.55

I would like to know what could be the possible reasons that the scores under these two experiments differ so much? In general what does this difference mean to the data set / model?

Thanks a lot in advance!

mango engineer